# Why "since $|b_n|\to\infty$, we may and do assume that $|b_n|\ge 1$ for every $n\ge 1$"?

Tags: limits

According to article, author wrote "since $|b_n|\to\infty$, we may and do assume that $|b_n|\ge 1$ for every  $n\ge 1$". Can you explain for me this? And what will $\sum\limits_{1\le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ become? (with $X_1$ be a random variable). Can I assum that  $|b_n|\ge a$ for all $n>1$? And then $\sum\limits_{1\le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ will become $\sum\limits_{a \le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ Thank you.

Comment: Any more information about $b_n$?

Comment: $\{b_n\}$ is a non-zero sequence of complex numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Since $|b_n| \to \infty$, we know that there exists an $N$ so that for all $n > N$, we have $|b_n| \geq 1$.  It's impossible to know for sure without context, but it looks like the writer is replacing the sequence $\{b_n\}$ with the sequence $\{b_{n+N}\}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: But what will $\sum\limits_{1\le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ become? Can I assume that  $|b_n|\ge a$ for all $n>1$? And then $\sum\limits_{1\le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ will become $\sum\limits_{a \le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $

Answer (score 1):

If the author was only interested in the limit of the sequence, only what happens when $n$ is sufficiently great is of interest. Here, $|b_n|\rightarrow \infty$ implies that there exists some $N$ such that for $n>N$, $|b_n|>1$. You can now consider the sequence $c_n = b_{n+N}$, which will verify the same properties of interest than $b_n$, and also verify $|c_n|>1$ for very $n\geq 1$. Now, you can forget about the old $(b_n)$ and rename $(c_n)$ into $(b_n)$ if you want to...

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: But what will $\sum\limits_{1\le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ become? Can I assume that  $|b_n|\ge a$ for all $n>1$? And then $\sum\limits_{1\le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $ will become $\sum\limits_{a \le |b_n| \le |X_1|} \dfrac{1}{|b_n|} $